# Recursive Web Link Search in PHP

Tags: php, recursion, hyperlink

I am trying to do recursive web link search using PHP, but the code doesn't seem to work. I get a timeout error.

```
function linksearch($url)
{
    $text = file_get_contents($url);
    if (!empty($text))
    {
        $res1 = preg_match_all("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",
        $text,
        $matches);
        if ($res1)
        {
           foreach(array_unique($matches[0]) as $link)
           {
              linksearch($url);
           }
        }
        else 
        {
            // echo "No links found.";
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: The problem comes from the file_get_content sentence doesn't it? focus your problem. The question title has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Where are you seeing the timeout? calling this method, or within it? As written, there seems to be no terminating condition for you method, not even a simple check to see if the URL has been tested recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a neverending loop there in your function, because you call your function again inside your function.

```
 linksearch($url);
```

You need a condition to terminate your function. That ain't no recursion, because on each iteration the input would change and end until some condition. Now it's the same all the time - $url.

Comment: Thanks got it. I have passed in $url as  a parameter which is wrong, instead of link

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you first save the page locally, and tune your script fetching a local test file, instead of having to run a remote call every time. You won't get a timeout error from the evaluation code that follows your file_get_contents(), unless the HTML file is humungously large.